# SQL "Case" statement when count(*) is 0

Tags: postgis, sql

I am trying to write the following SQL command using **case** clause.

```
with x as
(select the_geom as geom from table1
where st_dwithin(the_geom, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(28.959495,41.019913), 4326), 0.00012) limit 1)
select case count(geom)
when 0
    then st_setsrid(st_makepoint(28.959495,41.019913), 4326)
when 1
    then st_closestpoint(x.geom, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(28.959495,41.019913), 4326))       
end as the_geom
from x group by geom
```

As can be seen under the `with` clause, there could be either one row or no row in the record `x`. Code is working fine where there is one row in `x` but when the `x` is null (means `count(geom) = 0`) then the `when 0` operation is not getting executed. I am getting the following output. [image: output_1]

Plus, after modifying my SQL code a bit like the following (only the `when 2` is changed!)

```
with x as
(select the_geom as geom from table1
where st_dwithin(the_geom, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(28.959495,41.019913), 4326), 0.00012) limit 1)
select case count(geom)
when 0
then st_setsrid(st_makepoint(28.959495,41.019913), 4326)
when 2
then st_closestpoint(x.geom, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(28.959495,41.019913), 4326))       
end as the_geom
from x group by geom
```

The output is like the following screenshot when the `count(geom) = 1`. [image: output_2]

Queries:

1. How to run the `when 0` condition when the record `x` is empty?
2. What is the difference between the two SQL outputs (as shown in the screenshots)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify the whole thing by using `coalesce`, which selects the first non-null item in a list, in this case, either the nearest point to you search point, (28.959495,41.019913), or the point itself.

```
with input_geom (geom) as 
   (select st_setsrid(st_makepoint(28.959495,41.019913), 4326)) 
select coalesce(
   (select st_closestpoint(pts.the_geom, ig.geom) 
      where st_dwithin(ig.geom, pts.the_geom, 0.00012))
    ,ig.geom) as geom 
 from table1 pts, input_geom ig limit 1;
```

I have turned your query on its head, by putting the search point in the initial with statement, as this is both a search term or a return value, so it gets referred to in both parts of the `coalesce` statement.